# Bootstrap v5 Changed class names from .ml .mr to .ms .me, why?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Can someone clarify for me if there is any justified reason, why Bootstrap v5 changed names for such commonly used classes?

Comment: Most likely to facilitate switching between LTR and RTL with the same layout. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They did it because of the [RTL feature](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/12/07/bootstrap-5-beta-1/#renamed-classes-for-logical-properties):

> Part of our approach to adding RTL to Bootstrap was to add it in a way
> that felt future-friendly to ourselves and the web at large. As such,
> we’ve embraced the spirit of CSS logical properties and have renamed
> several classes and variables. It’s a risky change because of the size
> and impact of the change, but we hope you’ll appreciate it overall!
>
> Most of you have already interacted with logical properties thanks to
> our flex utilities—they replace direction properties like left and
> right in favor start and end. Things like align-items-end have been
> welcomed additions. This makes horizontal directional class names
> appropriate for LTR and RTL without any additional overhead moving
> forward.
>
> For example, in a LTR context, instead of .ml-3 for margin-left, use
> .ms-3.